# How to pass jsf form data to spring controller

Tags: java, spring, forms

I have Login form in **jsf** and a Login model that contains the fields

```
userID 
password
```

I want to pass form data to a Spring controller and set the login model using `@modeattribute` of Spring and call service of dao to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the way to do that :

first add this to your faces-config.xml :

```
<application>       
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

second write your controller like this :

```
@Controller
@Scope(value="session")
public class SomeContoller{

    private String userID;
    private String password;

    public String validate() {

       //some traitement on userID and password

       return "somepage";
     }

 //getters and setters ...
}
```

last of all add your dependencies : for spring and SpringBeanFacesELResolver